# SwiftyJSON array empty

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift2, swifty-json

I want to retrieve data from a JSON file with SwiftyJSON and Alamofire. This is the JSON data:

```
json: {
"data" : {
"monitors" : [
  {
    "lines" : [
      {
        "towards" : "LEOPOLDAU",
        "realtimeSupported" : true,
        "departures" : {
          "departure" : [
            {
              "departureTime" : {
                "countdown" : 2,
                "timePlanned" : "2015-09-09T18:47:03.000+0200",
                "timeReal" : "2015-09-09T18:47:03.000+0200"
              }
            },
            {
              "departureTime" : {
                "countdown" : 6,
                "timePlanned" : "2015-09-09T18:51:03.000+0200",
                "timeReal" : "2015-09-09T18:51:03.000+0200"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "lineId" : 301,
        "platform" : "1",
        "trafficjam" : false,
        "richtungsId" : "1",
        "direction" : "H",
        "type" : "ptMetro",
        "name" : "U1",
        "barrierFree" : true
      }
    ],
    "attributes" : {

    },
    "locationStop" : {
      "type" : "Feature",
      "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
          16.4330680046932,
          48.2430825589716
        ]
      },
      "properties" : {
        "municipality" : "Wien",
        "title" : "Kagran",
        "coordName" : "WGS84",
        "municipalityId" : 90000,
        "type" : "stop",
        "gate" : "1",
        "name" : "60200627",
        "attributes" : {
          "rbl" : 4127
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
}
 ,
"message" : {
"value" : "OK",
"serverTime" : "2015-09-09T18:45:08.998+0200",
"messageCode" : 1
  }
}
```

What I want to do now is get the data of lines into an array. I tried several combinations for that, e.g.

```
let departureArray = jsonData["data"]["monitors"][0]["lines"][0].array
```

or

```
let departureArray = jsonData["data"]["monitors"]["lines"].array
```

but my array is always empty. Does anyone has an idea how to do this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expected array `departureArray` is in fact a dictionary

```
let departureDictionary = jsonData["data"]["monitors"][0]["lines"][0].dictionary
```

Comment: you can see it in the source `"lines" : [  { ...` - The value of the key `lines` is an array (represented by `[`) which contains a dictionary (represented by `{`)